# access violation Joining a table on another table twice using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I got a table called matches containing 2 teams ID, and these teams are in the same table called clans

> matches
>
> team1_id | team2_id
>
> ```
>  2     |    4
>
>  1     |    2
>
>  4     |    1
> ```

and

> Clans
>
> ```
> ID | Name 
>
>  2 | abc 
>
>  1 | cde
>
>  4 | efg
> ```

My goal is that when I print this out at the webpage, it shows the teams names instead of their IDs. Now to explain it simple, I'm using laravel, with the following code:

```
    $unfinished = DB::table('matches')->where('team1_score', NULL)
        ->join('matches', 'matches.team1_id', '=', 'clans.id')
        ->join('matches', 'matches.team2_id', '=', 'clans.id')
        ->select('clans.clan_name as team1_name', 'clan_name as team2_name', 'matches.id'
        )->get();
```

and I need it all stored in $unfinished. Naturally, this code does'nt work, and I think I understand why. What i just can't figure out however, is how to solve this so that it will work.  It spits out the following exakt error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'matches' (SQL: select `clans`.`clan_name` as `team1_name`, `clan_name` as `team2_name`, `matches`.`id`, `tournaments`.`name` from `matches` inner join `tournaments` on `tournaments`.`id` = `matches`.`tournaments_id` inner join `matches` on `matches`.`team1_id` = `clans`.`id` inner join `matches` on `matches`.`team2_id` = `clans`.`id` where `team1_score` is null)

Comment: The SELECT is referencing columns from `clans`, but there is no rowsource named or aliased `clans`. If you need to reference the same table more than once, assign an alias to the table, and qualify column references with the alias. `DB::table('matches AS m')->where('m.team1_score',NULL)->join('matches AS m1','m1.team1_id', `...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
$unfinished = DB::table('matches')->where('team1_score', NULL)
    ->join('clans AS clans1', 'matches.team1_id', '=', 'clans1.id')
    ->join('clans AS clans2', 'matches.team2_id', '=', 'clans2.id')
    ->select('clans1.clan_name as team1_name', 'clans2.clan_name as team2_name', 'matches.id'
)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! greatly appriciated. Worked perfectly!